# Force FilteringSelect to lost focus after selecting a value

Tags: html, widget, focus, dojo

I'm using Dojo 1.6. I have a FilteringSelect connected to a datastore. I would like to empty the field when the user clicks on it, so the user does not need not remove anything. I have managed to do that by setting the textbox.value to "" upon focus:

```
dojo.connect(sel, 'onFocus', function (value) {
    this.textbox.value = ""
});
```

The issue I have is that when the user selects an element on the dropdown, the onChange gets fired, but the control does not lose the focus, so next time the user tries to modify the value, he needs to empty the field manually or click outside the control and then click back in the control. Is there any way I can force the control to lost the focus?

I've prepared a sample at http://jsfiddle.net/Jyvra/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Widget property you are looking to interact with in order to achieve this is the `focusNode`. Any widget that gets focus will have this, so simply add this line to your `onChange` handler:

```
this.focusNode.blur();
```

And you will be all set. You can check out your fiddle with that line added [right here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jyvra/11/).